# Заменить значения в одном столбце в зависимости от значений в нескольких других столбцах в dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Исходный data frame:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо по условию заменить значения в колонке SKU: если SKU == 207041 и warehouse == MSC и client == Тандер, то SKU = 916041

ожидаю получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
mask = (df['SKU']==207041) & (df['warehouse']=='MSC') & (df['client']=='Тандер')
df.loc[mask, 'SKU'] = 916041
```

или так:

```
idx = df.query("SKU==207041 and warehouse=='MSC' and client=='Тандер'").index
df.loc[idx, 'SKU'] = 916041
```

Comment: Спасибо! 1 вариант - полностью устраивает

Comment: @Timur, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)